# How to parse every match of sed command

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I have a string `[u'SOMEVALUE1', u'SOMEVALUE2', u'SOMEVALUE3']`, I would like to parse every element matched by my sed command. The element matched are in the single quote. Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
ARR="[u'SOMEVALUE1', u'SOMEVALUE1', u'SOMEVALUE1']"
for id in $(sed -n "s/^.*'\(.*\)'.*$/\1/ p" <<< ${ARR});
do
    echo "$id"
done
```

I have only the first value returned.

Comment: This looks like a mix of PHP and Python and Bash. If you have an actual Bash array, please show us the syntactically correct assignment.  If it's a string, the leading dollar sign is wrong.

Comment: Sorry it was a syntax error when I wrote the code on SO, it's a string.

Comment: I think you are getting the last value returned rather than the first value (you wouldn't notice since they are all named the same). This is because the `.*`, as tripleee wrote, matches the largest leftmost substring.

Comment: Add the expected output so we can help you. Right now it's not clear what you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcard `.*` will match the longest leftmost possible string. If your intention is to match the individual substrings which are in single quotes, try

```
grep -o "'[^']*'" <<<"$ARR"
```

To remove the single quotes around the values, simply pipe to `sed "s/'//g"` and to loop over the lines printed by a pipe, do

```
... commands ... |
while read -r id; do
    : things with "$id"
done
```

Comment: It's working but not like I expect. I mean `$id` take single quote, I expect to retreive the data contain between single quotes. I get value like `'SOMEVALUE1'`, I expect only `SOMEVALUE1`.

Comment: Still have the same problem, here is the code I used https://pastebin.com/dVwkSnid and the result I get from https://i.imgur.com/JTkOZ0y.png

Comment: If I add `sed "s/'//g"` after the pipe, the script is looping infinitly

Comment: Working, I needed to add a pipe againg after `sed "s/'//g"`

Comment: @executable when you find yourself adding pipe after pipe after pipe that's usually a sign there's something wrong. I can't tell from your question what it is you're really trying to do - you may want to ask a new, clearer question.

Answer (score 1):

BASH can match regular expressions with the help of `=~` (see [man bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)). Matching more than once is a bit painful but in your case we can split the input on white space and match once per item:

```
ARR="[u'SOMEVALUE1', u'SOMEVALUE1', u'SOMEVALUE1']"
for A in $ARR
do
    [[ $A =~ u\'(.+)\' ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
done
```

results in

```
SOMEVALUE1
SOMEVALUE1
SOMEVALUE1
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ ARR="[u'SOMEVALUE1', u'SOMEVALUE1', u'SOMEVALUE1']"

$ awk -v RS="'" '!(NR%2)' <<< "$ARR"
SOMEVALUE1
SOMEVALUE1
SOMEVALUE1

$ awk -v RS="'" '!(NR%2)' <<< "$ARR" |
while IFS= read -r id; do echo "id=$id"; done
id=SOMEVALUE1
id=SOMEVALUE1
id=SOMEVALUE1
```